# div set to 100% wont work

Tags: css, html

here is my site
http://iadprint.com/about

i am trying to make the menu tag and the colright div to have a height of 100%  and stick to the footer div pushing down to the bottom. but no matter what i try nothing works. i have tried validating the html but only 3 errors exist which arent that important to fix. what ami doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of fixed layouts for this sort of scenario where you want a footer to always appear at the bottom of the window:

```
header
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
}

nav
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

article
{
    top: 130px;
    bottom: 120px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

footer
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [faux background technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), [CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) (possibly with `table-cell`) or [JavaScript](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/).